# Is there a way to call a method of a stateless widget to another stateless widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, stateless

Here, I have two files dot_indicator.dart and main.dart.

The function which is inside the Dots class "updatePosition()", how can it be accessed inside the onPageChanged of the PageView widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dots_indicator/dots_indicator.dart';

class Dots extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DotsState createState() => _DotsState();
}

class _DotsState extends State<Dots> {
  final _totalDots = 2;
  double currentPosition = 0.0;

  double validPosition(double position) {
    if (position >= _totalDots) return 0;
    if (position < 0) return _totalDots - 1.0;
    return position;
  }

  void updatePosition(double position) {
    setState(() => currentPosition = validPosition(position));
  }

  String getCurrentPositionPretty() {
    return (currentPosition + 1.0).toStringAsPrecision(2);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DotsIndicator(
      dotsCount: _totalDots,
      position: currentPosition,
      decorator: DotsDecorator(
        activeColor: Colors.green,
        activeSize: Size.square(30.0),
        activeShape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This widget had the function updatePosition(index), I want to access it in another class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_app/bottom_nav.dart';
import 'package:mobile_app/dot_indicator.dart';
import 'package:mobile_app/first_page.dart';
import 'package:mobile_app/second_page.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(250, 250, 250, 100),
          elevation: 0.0,
          title: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Dots(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: PageSlider(),
        bottomNavigationBar: AppBottomNav(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  const PageSlider({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PageSliderState createState() => _PageSliderState();
}

class _PageSliderState extends State<PageSlider> {

  Dots _dots = new Dots();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PageController controller = PageController(initialPage: 0, keepPage: true);
    return PageView(
      controller: controller,
      onPageChanged: (index) => {
        print(index),
        //I want the updatePosition(index) here
      },
      children: <Widget>[
        FirstPage(),
        SecondPage(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I tried making the instance of the Dots class and tried to use it inside the PageSlider class, it still wont work.

Comment: You can try static keyword before declaring your method.

Comment: In dart `_` undescore means private. Try removing underscore from `_DotsState`class and create an object for `DotsState` class and access that method. But this is in not an efficient/recommended way to do it.